# PHP: Return value associated with specific key in an array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

In PHP 5.5+, how do I check if the given array of associative arrays contains specific key/value pairs. For example:

```
$some_array = array(
            array(
                "value"=> 1,
                "k1"=> "austin",
                "k2"=> "texas",
                "k3"=> "us"
            ),
            array(
                "value"=> 15,
                "k1"=> "bali",
                "k2"=> "ubud",
                "k3"=> "indonesia"
            ),
            array(
                "value"=> 26,
                "k1"=> "hyd",
                "k2"=> "telangana",
                "k3"=> "india"
            )
));
```

How do I return the value associated with k1='bali', k2='ubud' and k3='indonesia'? I can loop through each element to check if that combination exists in the array but is there a simpler way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an target array of keys and values, you can filter the main array to only include child arrays that match all the key/value combinations in your target array using `array_diff_assoc`.

```
$target =array(
    "k1"=> "bali",
    "k2"=> "ubud",
    "k3"=> "indonesia"
);

$matches = array_filter($some_array, function($item) use ($target) {
    return !array_diff_assoc($target, $item);
});
```

Inside the `array_filter` callback, `array_diff_assoc` will return all the key/value pairs in `$target` that are not present in `$item`, so if they all match, you'll get an empty array. Negating that result with `!` will return `true` for matching arrays and `false` for non-matching arrays.

`$matches` will be an array of all the child arrays matching your set of key/value pairs, or an empty array if none match.